# Tem como desfazer o comando "git reset HEAD~1"?

Tags: git

Estava querendo voltar para o último commit realizado, e nada funciona mais, queria saber se tem como desfazer o comando git reset

Comment: cara, acho q isso deve resolver `git reset 'HEAD@{1}'`

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510276/undoing-git-reset

Comment: peguei dessa mesma referencia que o @IsraelMerljak comentou, testei aqui num código lero que tenho e funcionou.

Comment: na verdade já testei isso @IsraelMerljak, mas ainda sim não consegui recuperar

Comment: na verdade estava dando erro nos pacotes no node_modules (bibliotecas npm), eu reenistalei os arquivos, sumiu os erros e apareceram outros, eu executei o git reset, e minha página não consegue mais carregar os arquivos .js

Comment: você me recomendariam puxar do repositório remoto do bitbucket? to pensando em deletar tudo e puxar do repositório.

Answer (score 3):

Galera depois de pesquisar um pouco achei um material bem interessante que me auxiliou bastante, segue o link: http://minicursogit.github.io/#/

**1º Sempre que houver uma modificação pertinente no seu código, lembre do git commit:**

Graças ao bom pai tenho a boa prática de commitar sempre que uma modificação é feita no sistema, mesmo tendo pouca prática com o git, e eu tinha o commit do dia anterior onde estava tudo funcionando, salvo algumas modificações bem irrelevantes.

**2º desfazendo mudanças indesejadas no git:**

- **git checkout**

"Se eu me arrepender das minhas últimas alterações?"

"Você pode descartar mudanças no seu working directory voltando o estado dos seus arquivos para o último salvo na staging area."

Sendo que pode ser feita a partir do id do seu commit ou a partir dos seus arquivos, exemplos:

- git checkout id_commit
- git checkout arquivo
- git checkout . *(comando executado)*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: boa explicação, que bom que conseguiu resolver sozinho +1

Comment: Vou deixar o meu +1 também, começando em `Git` vejo que é uma excelente resposta!

Comment: muito obrigado pessoal, gostei bastante do material